# mvc2 file links save as

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i have a view with a list of files which is returned from the database.
each file is a href to my controller action:

```
<a href="/Attachment/DownloadFile/3667">New Text Document.txt</a>

public virtual FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
        {
            var result = _domainService.QueryAttachment(id);
            return File(result.FileData, result.MimeType, result.FileName);
        }
```

the 3667 is the id of the file stored in SQL.
how do i go about enabling the right click 'save as' that you see on other sites?
when i do, it just saves the html rather than fetching the file from controller.

it might not be possible via storing files in SQL.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah silly me.. it does allow for Save-As but only IE.
firefox has its own tricks